# how to make node.js server not accesible via browser but still available to nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to run my node.js application on port 3000. I am using nginx as a reverse proxy server to communicate with node.js internally. Nginx is working fine but node.js server is also available if I try to run it with the server ip and port.

I want that my node.js server is not accessible via browser and it only communicates via nginx server internally.

I am running my node server on http and https on nginx server. Both the node server and the nginx server are running on a vm with CentOS(Linux). I want that the node.js server should not be accessible outside the vm even through any browser on my windows laptop neither from the outside world

Can someone kindly guide me about how to achieve it?

Comment: You need appropriate firewall settings for that.  Your node.js server needs to be configured such that it can't be accessed from the outside world, only from your local LAN or from your NGINX server. This is a network configuration/security issue, not a software issue.  You don't say what type of network you're on, but you should have some sort of firewall that can be configured to block access to your servers's actual IP address from the outside world, while still allowing nginx to access it.

Comment: There is so much information lacking from this question... are you running an HTTP service with Node.js?  And if so, using what method?  Where is Nginx running?  Are you trying to prevent browsers locally, or outside of this machine?  Please include more details with your questions.  In the mean time, I made a bunch of assumptions and answered your question anyway.

Comment: I am running my node server on http and https on nginx server. Both the node server and the nginx server are running on a vm with CentOS(Linux). I want that the node.js server should not be accessible outside the vm even through any browser on my windows laptop neither from the outside world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want that my node.js server is not accessible via browser and it only communicates via nginx server internally.

I assume by "via browser", you mean via other users, and not a browser on localhost.  I also assume you're using the built-in HTTP/S server, either directly or via something like Express.  Finally, I assume Nginx is running on the same host.  If these assumptions aren't correct, you should edit your question to clarify, and show some code.

Now, when you call `.listen()` to start the server, there are optional parameters you can pass to set the port **and** bind host.  For example, if I did this:

```
server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', ...);
```

This would start a server that listens on port `3000`, but only accepts connections when made from `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`.  This means that anything on that machine can connect to `:3000` and make requests, but requests from other hosts won't work.

Comment: I am running my node server on http and https on nginx server. Both the node server and the nginx server are running on a vm with CentOS(Linux). I already tried your solution but when I save the changes, the node server is not even accessible to the nginx server and the application does not start on the browser outside the vm on the browser.

Comment: @sourabhjha Then, you need to check your Nginx config and ensure you're using localhost or some hostname that resolves to `127.0.0.1` for the upstream.  Also, if you've already tried something, you need to put that in your question.  It's frustrating and waste of everyone's time.  We could have helped you with your config straight away, but instead you didn't include enough information.

Comment: I was using my vm's IP in upstream. when I changed it to 127.0.0.1, it worked. Thank you Brad and apologies for not providing enough information initially. I really appreciate your help